# Jquery not loading with relative path / IPhone Safari

Tags: jquery, iphone, url

Anybody who knows why jquery only loads with the http://ajax... URL and not with my files on the ftp server?

I copy pasted the code and it works on all browser except the safari brwoser on the IPhone if I am using the file on my server???

Any idea?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>


            <!--
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this instead :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you add the "./" to the css too ?

Comment: No it doesn't work! I am writing a php solution which checks whether the file on google exists and if not, it should load my local files...so I think I managed the problem, but I really think it is something strange...I also heard that some browser could not load more than 2 JavaScript Files...Perhaps safari on the IPhone is one of them...